# How to update CloudKit public database with data from third-party REST API

Tags: ios, rest, scripting, server-side, cloudkit

I would like to update the public database of CloudKit for a mobile app with data from a third-party REST API. For example, I will start with several records in CloudKit, each of which contains the identifier of a record in the third-party REST API. If possible, I would like to write a script that pulls data from that API on a timed schedule and updates the corresponding CloudKit records.

I see that CloudKit JS is available, but I don't think this is what I need, since I am not trying to do anything with a web app here. I also know that the database can be updated from within an app, and that this is not what I need to do.

I believe the terminology for this is server-side logic. Is there any way I can use server-side logic to update the public database of CloudKit with data from a third-party REST API? I am not asking for the code to do this, but if it can be done using the tools available from CloudKit, and if anyone can point me in the right direction.

EDIT: UPDATE: Seems like maybe I have to run php from my own server to update iCloud database.

Comment: You cannot call a REST API from within CloudKit.  Apple does provide a Web Service API in addition to the Javascript API though, here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/

Comment: You can make that the answer if you would like.